Flutter Web: Only loads app update after second reload
In my Flutter web app, when I release a new version and open the URL, it still displays the old version. You have to reload the page before you see the new one.
This happens if you have previously opened the web app before and gets critical when breaking changes were made to the backend.
Funnily enough when you use package_info_plus to display the current app version, it displays the correct version.
I assume this is due to cache stored from the last session. Is there a way of clearing this cache?

Maybe we can refresh the web app immediately after the page is visited. Not a Great UX. say
html.window.location.reload();

So I left a comment before, but after further research, I stumbled upon a medium article on updating flutter web apps by adding or updating your app version number in index.html at the flutter initialisation js script. like below.
    <head>
     ......
      <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
      <script src="flutter.js?version=1" defer></script>
    </head>

So I guess just bump it up as new updates are released and you don't want the cached version to be used. I actually thought this will mess with the flutter.js version instead, but it worked.

Link to the article? :)

In version before Flutter 3.22 in index.html I used the following code:
<body>
 <script src="preload_script.js"></script>
 <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', async function (ev) {
      const versionResponse = await fetch('/version.json?version=' + Date.now());
      const versionJson = await versionResponse.json();
      const version = versionJson['version'];
      console.log(version);
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        entrypointUrl: '/main.dart.js?version=' + version,
        onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
 </script>
</body>

The most important line here

entrypointUrl: '/main.dart.js?version=' + version,

Thus, forcing the main.dart.js file to be loaded from the server.
To force the application to update, you need to raise the version in pubspec.yaml

version: 1.0.0+1 change to version: 1.0.1

After Flutter 3.22 you need to create a flutter_bootstrap.js file in the /web folder, next to the index.html file with the following content.
{{flutter_js}}
{{flutter_build_config}}

window.addEventListener('load', async function (ev) {
  const versionResponse = await fetch('/version.json?version=' + Date.now());
  const versionJson = await versionResponse.json();
  const version = versionJson['version'];
  console.log(version);
  // Download main.dart.js
  _flutter.loader.load({
    serviceWorkerSettings: {
      timeoutMillis: 40000,
      serviceWorkerUrl: "flutter_service_worker.js?version_worker=" + version,
      serviceWorkerVersion: {{flutter_service_worker_version}},
    },
  });
});

This time we force load flutter_service_worker

serviceWorkerUrl: "flutter_service_worker.js?version_worker=" + version,

To force the application to update, you need to raise the version in pubspec.yaml

version: 1.0.0+1 change to version: 1.0.1


Answers must be written in English
